# Trouble in 2nd order differential

Tags: calculus

$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=-\frac{k}{x}$$

How do I approach this type of a question? I've never seen one before. I tried putting $\frac{dx}{dt}=y$ but it didn't work out.

I haven't been taught the characteristic roots method for solving these, so I'm looking for a different solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using chain rule you have:

$$\dot{x}\frac{d\dot x}{dx} = -\frac{k}{x}\\
\implies\frac{dx}{dt} = \sqrt{ -2k\ln(x) +C} $$

Now can you proceed? I cannot solve this integral so I left it here.

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with the dot notation either :(

Comment: @Gaurang Its just $\dot{x} = \frac{dx}{dt}$.

Comment: Ok, $$\frac{d(dx/dt)}{dt}=-\frac{k}{x}$$ implies $$\frac{dx}{dt}d(\frac{dx}{dt})=-\frac{k}{x}dx$$ which can now be integrated. Understood, thanks!

Comment: But, how did you get the $2k$ in it? I seem to only be getting a $k$...

Comment: You will get $\frac{(\dot{x})^2}{2}$ on the left side.

Comment: ok, thanks.....

Comment: Btw could you solve the last integral?

Comment: I was only supposed to find the velocity ($v=dx/dt$) so I stopped there. Though, yes, the last integral is strange. The [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?t=crmtb01&f=ob&i=dx%2Fdt%3D%5Csqrt%7Blnx%7D) entry is unsatisfying. I can't come up with anything...